# Error VS30063: You are not authorized to access

Tags: tfs

I tried to create a TFS agent in a new server. I had enabled anonymous authentication also. but not working.

```
Enter server URL > http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:8080/
tfs Enter authentication type (press enter for Integrated) > 
Connecting to server ... 
VS30063:You are not authorized to access http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:8080. Failed to
connect.  Try again or ctrl-c to quit
```

Comment: You must make sure the service account for Team Foundation Build is a member of the Build Services group. You must also make sure that the account has read/write permissions to the temporary folders and the ASP.NET temporary folder. please see the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/ms253149(v=vs.120)

Answer (score 0):

Please do these steps for the manual agent installation.

**Prerequisites:**

1- make sure ports 80, 8080, and 443 are opened between the agent server and the TFS server.

2- Ensure your user is an administrator in TFS Security [Team Foundation Administrators].

3- download the agent files from the TFS server portal.
[image]

**In agent server:**

1- put agent files after extracting them in any path, we will use "C:\azagent"

2- run PowerShell as administrator.

3- run these commands:

> cd *C:\azagent*

> .\config.cmd --deploymentgroup --deploymentgroupname "*AnyNameInTFS*" --agent *$env:COMPUTERNAME* --runasservice --work '_work' --url 'http://00.00.00.00/tfs/' --collectionname '*DefaultCollection*' --projectname '*TestDeploymentProcess*' --auth Negotiate;

3- enter your username don't forget the domain.

4- enter the password.

and it's done successfully.